# Why do browsers use `Accept: */*` for <script> tags, instead of application/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Firefox and Chrome would claim they prefer a html or xml document when doing the request for the page, like this (from Chrome):

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

and `text/css` for `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, like:

```
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
```

But when it comes to `<script src>`, it becomes

```
Accept: */*
```

without claiming `application/javascript` despite it will accept only javascript.

Why would it behave like that ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#notes says to use `text/javascript`, but notes that only audio and video responses are blocked because browsers are lenient, likely because several content-types are in-use and whitelisting would break the web, which users would blame on the browser.

Comment: @dandavis yeah `text/javascript` or `application/javascript`, but it is not `*/*` anyway.

Comment: @dandavis And it is no harm to make it `Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, */*;q=0.1` like what they do for css.

Comment: It's true there's no harm in a more specific header, but it's also true there's no real benefit either. It makes sense to distinguish and prefer certain media formats for optimization, but script is script. Given that, why bog down the request packet with extra length that serves no purpose on one of (if not) the most common flavors of http requests? That's a waste of time, bandwidth, battery,  server CPU cycles, etc.

Comment: The browser know it is a `<script>` tag, but the server may not. The tag may refer to, lets say, `https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.js` which is indeed not a script file if you open it in a browser. And anyway I am not suggesting doing so. I am justing asking why not since they already did that for css.

Answer (score 1):

It reduces the size of the Accept header and thus saves some bandwidth leading to a performance boost.

See [bug 170789](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170789)

Also, it helps to minimize errors on sites expecting headers of fixed maximum length.

See [IE and the Accept Header (IEInternals' MSDN blog)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/ie-and-the-accept-header)